# Adding columns in data frame as a-z (26) new columns

Tags: r, dataset, data-science

Each column will read the Name from the Name column and add the frequency of the alphabet in the corresponding column.
I want to add 26 new columns to my data frame. I am using

```
mydata3$a = str_count(mydata3$Name, "a")
mydata3$b = str_count(mydata3$Name, "b")
mydata3$c = str_count(mydata3$Name, "c")
mydata3$d = str_count(mydata3$Name, "d")
mydata3$e = str_count(mydata3$Name, "e")
mydata3$f = str_count(mydata3$Name, "f")
mydata3$g = str_count(mydata3$Name, "g")
mydata3$h = str_count(mydata3$Name, "h")
mydata3$i = str_count(mydata3$Name, "i")
mydata3$j = str_count(mydata3$Name, "j")
mydata3$k = str_count(mydata3$Name, "k")
mydata3$l = str_count(mydata3$Name, "l")
mydata3$m = str_count(mydata3$Name, "m")
mydata3$n = str_count(mydata3$Name, "n")
mydata3$o = str_count(mydata3$Name, "o")
mydata3$p = str_count(mydata3$Name, "p")
mydata3$q = str_count(mydata3$Name, "q")
mydata3$r = str_count(mydata3$Name, "r")
mydata3$s = str_count(mydata3$Name, "s")
mydata3$t = str_count(mydata3$Name, "t")
mydata3$u = str_count(mydata3$Name, "u")
mydata3$v = str_count(mydata3$Name, "v")
mydata3$w = str_count(mydata3$Name, "w")
mydata3$x = str_count(mydata3$Name, "x")
mydata3$y = str_count(mydata3$Name, "y")
mydata3$z = str_count(mydata3$Name, "z")
```

I want to make a function for this in R. Please help

```
output:
      Name Gender a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
1     emma      F 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2   olivia      F 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
3      ava      F 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
4   sophia      F 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 isabella      F 2 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
6      mia      F 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The `letters` will provide the lower case alphabets, using that we can easily create columns by looping through it using `lapply`

```
library(stringr)
mydata3[letters] <- lapply(letters, function(x) str_count(mydata3$Name, x))
```

---

Another option would be do split the 'Name' column, get the frequency with `table`

```
cbind(mydata3, as.data.frame.matrix(table(transform(stack(setNames(strsplit(mydata3$Name, 
         ""), seq_len(nrow(mydata3))))[2:1] , values = factor(values, levels = letters)))))
#   Name Gender a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
#1     emma      F 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#2   olivia      F 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
#3      ava      F 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
#4   sophia      F 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#5 isabella      F 2 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#6      mia      F 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

#### data

```
mydata3 <- structure(list(Name = c("emma", "olivia", "ava", "sophia", "isabella", 
"mia"), Gender = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F")), .Names = c("Name", 
 "Gender"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```